# Need to type a function using $Subtype and generics

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I’m trying to use `$Subtype` to type a mixin function. I believe my type signature is correct. I keep getting some errors:

```
const MyMixin: MixinFunction = superclass => class extends superclass {};
                                             ^ Cannot extend `superclass` [1] with
                                               `<<anonymous class>>` because `A` [2] is
                                               not inheritable.
```

Here is my super simple code ([on Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCyAlgB7EB2AYgK4UDGGxcFYAvGADwCCAfABQBnGvgBO9GAENBggFxgAwlJk9eASna9FywZwAkAZRoAjbPlW8A3KnotBGIlhLkK855VoMmLdmGFiJaUFNMECZMDxSDDwKABNg-zxxHTAAbwBfSyA)):

```
type MixinFunction = <A>(superclass: Class<A>) => Class<$Subtype<A>>;

const MyMixin: MixinFunction = superclass => class extends superclass {};
```

How can I made this code work without errors?